# Adding SSL Certs via mounted volume causing permissions issue

Tags: postgresql, docker

In my docker-compose.yml, I'm using the following to mount SSL certs into my container:

`- ./certs:/var/lib/postgresql/certs`

The ./certs folder and everything within it is owned by root locally.

However, upon starting the container, I receive:

```
2022-08-26 20:04:40.623 UTC [1] FATAL:  could not load server certificate file "/var/lib/postgresql/certs/db.crt": Permission denied
```

Updating the permissions locally to anything else (777,755, etc..) results in a separate error:

```
FATAL:  private key file "/var/lib/postgresql/certs/postgresdb.key" has group or world access
```

I realize I can copy the certs via my Dockerfile, but I'd rather not have to build a new image each time I want to change certificates.  What is the best way to go about handling this?

Answer (score 0):

Change the ownership of the certs to the user that's used inside the container, before you start the container.

You need to double-check the id of the user, since you didn't show what image you run. Below is an example.

```bash
sudo chmod -R 400 ./certs
sudo chown -R 5432:5432 ./certs
```

Alternatively, you can run the container with your local user ID. I only recommend this for development purpose.

```bash
docker run --user "$(id -u)" postgres
```

In that case, also make sure your local user has permissions on the certs dir.

Comment: I'm using https://hub.docker.com/layers/koehn/postgres-wal-g/14.4-v2.0.0/images/sha256-46b386d73dd6b23c98655cc63ed2b539b653e17300d6dddf7ac8aa6bd51e340d?context=explore

I set chmod to 400 and chown to 999:999  and am still receiving the same issue.